# scapy: struct.error: cannot convert argument to integer

Tags: python, python-2.7, scapy, pcap

I'm using scapy to write to construct network packets and write to a pcap file. I'm getting `struct.error: cannot convert argument to integer` error while writing them, although I converted the TCP port numbers to `unsigned short` using ctypes in python.

```
def create_packet(sip, dip, sport, dport, payload):
      sp = ctypes.c_ushort(sport)
      dp = ctypes.c_ushort(dport)
      packet = IP(src = sip, dst = dip)/TCP(sport=sp, 
               dport=dp)/str(payload.replace(' ','').decode("hex"))
      return packet

def write_packet(file, pkt):
      wrpcap(file, pkt, append=True)
```

Edit#1:
The error was due to the huge payload string that was passing to the write to pcap function.

Comment: What does `self.i2m(pkt,val)` return?

Comment: doc string says: Converts internal value to machine value 
       `def i2m(self, pkt, x):
             """Convert internal value to machine value"""
             if x is None:
                 x = 0
               return x`

Comment: why are you using `ctypes.c_ushort` for ports and not just plain `int`? Try changing to `sp = ctypes.c_ushort(sport).value` (also for `dp`) and check again...

Comment: I use ctypes to convert int to unsigned short as it is expecting the port numbers to be unsigned short. @coder I changed as you suggested. I get following error.
      `Traceback (most recent call last):

       write_packet(pcap_file, res_pkt)
      File "xml_parser.py", line 78, in write_packet
         wrpcap(f, pkt, append=True) 
    File "scapy/layers/inet.py", line 500, in post_build
    ln)
struct.error: 'H' format requires 0 <= number <= 65535`

Comment: who is expecting port numbers to be unsigned short? if `scapy`, then `scapy` works fine with ints

Comment: Yes, but even after converting the ints to unsigned shorts, I get `struct.error: 'H' format requires 0 <= number <= 65535` error.

Comment: The format specifier 'H' means unsigned short https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters 
I'm getting this error when I'm trying to write the packets to a pcap file.

Comment: I think that you are trying to do some things manually while `scapy` offers you the functionality to do them in a more easy way, thus the errors. From the small code snippets you posted unfortunately I can't help you. As a first step I would try to find where exactly the error occurs and then post that part of the code. Generally creating and writing a packet with `scapy` is much simpler, you don't even need to use `ctypes`...

Comment: If it tells you `requires 0 <= number <= 65535` then don't paste the error message to us without telling us what `number` is!